# Can you configure a window so that if you resize from any edge none of the window's controls change location relative to the monitor?

Tags: c#, winforms

I noticed today if you resize from the bottom or the right of a window the controls on the screen stay still: they don't move.

But if you resize from the left or the top the controls on the screen move just as many pixels as you resize.

I'm wondering: can I configure the window to resize the same (controls on the screen don't move) whether they use the right/bottom edge or the left/top edge?

The reason being: What if they want to resize the window to show only the area they want, and that area happens to be in the bottom right?

The best solution would implement this resize mode if they make the window smaller than the default size, and use the normal resize mode if they make the window larger.

Thanks!

Comment: use `Anchor` and `Dock` features on the controls

Comment: thats not what i want. i want the ability to make the window smaller than normal and show any sub-area of the original window that i want.

Answer (score 0):

you can catch & handle resize event of windows --> re-layout the vision of your window.

> I noticed today if you resize from the bottom or the right of a window the controls on the screen stay still: they don't move.

Default value of FlowDirection is LeftToRight ->  origin of the coordinates axis will be top & left point. You can change to RightToLeft.

An UI object have a attribute name cliptobound, it will help you place an element out of window size.

Above stuff can not answer exactly your question --> But i hope it can give an idea to solve.